# Is $(\mathbb{Z}, \times)$ also a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, arithmetic, computer-science

Addition $+$ is a closure operation for set of integers ($\mathbb{Z}$)

The identity element for set of integers is $0$

---

Definition of group:

> Each group is a set of elements with one operation $*$ and  is closed under $*$. Each element in the group has an inverse. Each element combine with its inverse gives the identity element $e$.

---

So, $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ is a group

Is $(\mathbb{Z}, \times)$ also a group?

Comment: Multiplication is a well-defined operation on $\mathbb{Z}$. While a single group has only one operation in its data, there is no restriction on how many operations can *exist* on a set. In other words, $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ and $(\mathbb{Z},\times)$ are both things that may or may not be groups, because $+$ and $\times$ are both operations $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$. It turns out that $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is a group, but $(\mathbb{Z},\times)$ is not a group. Can you see why?

Comment: I don't think the term "closure operation" means anything. The integers are closed under both the operations addition and multiplication. The integers with the operation of addition is a group, with multiplication not.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk for (Z, x) identity element is 1 but each element does not have its inverse? this is why it is not group

Comment: Some do, some don't. You should give an explicit example of one that doesn't if you want to say it's not a group.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC number `2` does not have its inverse. number `1` has its inverse. so (Z,×) is not a group

Comment: Very nice! That's correct — because $1$ is the identity element under multiplication and there is no integer $x$ such that $2x = 1$, $(\mathbb{Z},\times)$ is not a group.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Is the motivation behind introducing **Group defintion** to solve equations? what is the exact motivation behind this abstract concept?

Comment: There are many motivations for studying groups. Indeed they can help us solve certain types of equations, but also do much, much, much more. While it's hard to overstate their importance, it's also hard to effectively convey how useful they are before you've learned more math. Here's one example: the proof of Fermat's Little Theorem can be done carefully in a couple paragraphs by using induction + the binomial theorem, or in a single line using elementary group theory!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk How to find all groups of order 4? Clue given is: there are 4 possible cayley tables, but 3 are identical to each other. There are only two distinct groups of order 4

Comment: That hint is correct. Have you tried making the Cayley tables? Also, have you done the simpler problem of finding all groups of orders 1, 2, and 3?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk yes I did for order 1 , 2 & 3 with rules of cayley table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110881/discussion-between-diracdeltafunk-and-overexchange).

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: I read your chat room discussion. What an excellent teaching session you conducted. I hope you either currently or plan in the future to teach more.

Comment: Thank you so much! I hope to teach as much as possible in my career :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's analyze the group, $(\mathbb{Z}, \times)$. First, we need an identity element. In this group, $1$ would be our identity element (there's your first condition). Now, it's also easy to see that $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed under multiplication. However, a problem arises with inverses. For any integer, $a$, $a \times \frac{1}{a} = 1$. However, for most integers, $\frac{1}{a}$ is not an element of $\mathbb{Z}$. For example, $3 \times \frac{1}{3} = 1$, but $\frac{1}{3}$ isn't an element of $\mathbb{Z}$

Definition of a Group:

1. (Closure) A set, $G$, is a group if it is closed under some binary operator, *
2. (Identity) There is an identity element, $e$, in G such that $a * e = a$ for all $a$ in $G$
3. (Inverse) For every $a \in G$, there exists an element, $a^{-1}$, such that $a * a^{-1} = e$

Comment: What is the motivation behind **Group definition**?

Comment: @overexhange I included the definition of a group in my answer. The "group" you defined fails criteria $3$. Is this what you mean behind motivation?

Comment: I mean, where do we apply the concept of group definition? Solving equations

Comment: @overexchange Well, one could think of a group in terms of symmetries. i.e. the dihedral group. The dihedral group, $D_4$ gives us the symmetries of a square

Comment: In computer science, [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) is a *mathematical model for data types. An abstract data type is defined by its behavior (semantics) from the point of view of a user, of the data, specifically in terms of possible values, possible operations on data of this type, and the behavior of these operations.* From the motivation aspect, Is group definition something to do with designing new abstract data type, given a problem statement?

Comment: In computer science it is often necessary to solve problems of different kind. For example, operations on actual objects that are employed in animation, gaming and (more abstractly) differential equations. For example a translation in the periodic function $f(x)$ by a number $c$ (smaller than the period) can be equivalent to action of a rotation $R$ about the axis of a disk by an angle $\theta$. These seemingly unrelated operations can be obtained via bijections from the action of a group that is independent of the actual problem (function of a mechanical rotation in the examples above).

Comment: @Basco Amidst problem solving, in computer science, we derive set of data elements and operations on those data elements. So, I was wondering, if defining a group is similar to designing new abstract data type?

Comment: @overexchange Probably a more broad response (like those here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449066/do-groups-rings-and-fields-have-practical-applications-in-cs-if-so-what-are-s) would be more appealing.

Comment: @N.Bar small typo, "$1 \times \frac{1}{3}$" should read $3 \times \frac{1}{3}$. Also on a very nitpicky level, the argument you use should include the point that inverses are unique in $\mathbb{Q}$ so the fact that $1/3$ is the inverse of $3$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ is enough to not check anything else in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey Thanks for catching that! And I was just trying to provide one simple counterexample for the OP, but you are certainly correct.

Answer (score 3):

The way you've stated is a bit too simplistic. We aren't interested in making extremely generic statements like "The set can have one and only one operation defined on it." when we're defining algebraic structures.

If we could PROVE that it can have one and only one operation defined on it, then that would be neat. But we don't say that a priori.

Here's the formal definition of a group.

Let $G$ be a set and $\circ: G \times G \to G$ be a function. Then, the pair $(G, \circ)$ is called a group iff the following statements hold:

1. $\forall a,b,c \in G: a \circ (b \circ c) = (a \circ b) \circ  c$
2. $\exists e \in G: \forall a \in G: a \circ e = a = e \circ a$
3. $\forall a \in G: \exists b \in G: a \circ b = e = b \circ a$

That's it. So, for instance, $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is a group, where we are careful in specifying that $+$ is the usual addition on the integers.

Now, this doesn't imply that a multiplication operation cannot be defined on $\mathbb{Z}$. You and I multiply integers on a daily basis and certainly, we get integers when we multiply integers with integers. In that sense, we say that $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed under multiplication. However, we note that $(\mathbb{Z},\cdot)$ is NOT a group.

We can see that not all elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ have a multiplicative inverse that is contained in $\mathbb{Z}$. For example, we note that $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ is the identity element BUT:

$$2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} = 1 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1$$

so $\frac{1}{2}$ is an inverse of $2$ but it isn't actually an integer. So, $(\mathbb{Z}, \cdot)$ fails to satisfy the third condition and hence, it isn't a group.

Answer (score 1):

A single set can have two different operations defined on it, both of which make it a group. And "$\mathbb Z$ with $+$"  would be considered to be a different group from "$\mathbb Z$ with $\times$" (assuming both are groups).

As for "$\mathbb Z$ with $\times$", think about inverses.

Also, I don't know if there's some language barrier, but asking if something "is a closure operation" isn't how one talks about groups. I'm pretty sure you're asking "Does $\mathbb Z$ form a group under $\times$?".

In group theory, "closure" is a property of an operation on a set which means when you perform the operation on two members of the set you get back another element of the set. So, for example, the odd numbers are **not** closed under addition.

Answer (score 1):

> **Definition:** An *idempotent* with respect to an operation $\ast:S\times S\to S$ is an element $e\in S$ such that $e\ast e=e$.

> **Lemma:** Each group has exactly one idempotent; namely, the identity.

*Proof:* Let $(G,\circ)$ be a group with identity $e$. Suppose $g\in G$ is an idempotent. Then $$g\circ g=g=g\circ e.\tag{1}$$ Multiply $(1)$ on the left by $g^{-1}$. Then

$$\begin{align}
g^{-1}\circ(g\circ g)&=(g^{-1}\circ g)\circ g\\
&=e\circ g\\
&=g\\
&=g^{-1}\circ (g\circ e)\\
&=(g^{-1}\circ g)\circ e\\
&=g^{-1}\circ g\\
&=e.
\end{align}$$

So, in particular, $g=e$. $\square$

But for $0$ and $1$ in $\Bbb Z$, $0\times 0=0$, $1\times 1=1$, and $0\neq 1$; thus $(\Bbb Z,\times)$ cannot be a group by the lemma above.

Comment: This probably isn't appropriate to the O.P.'s level, but is a very slick way of doing it (plus it uses idempotents, which I have a personal fondness for). +1.

Comment: Thank you, @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC.