# Applications of group theory/abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, applications

Before voting down, I would this text to be read.

This is not exactly a question regarding a hint to solve an exercise of a list or an exam, but a question involving the possible utility of which is my favourite Mathematics branch: group theory. As far as I have heard, group theory has not as much applications as other branches such as Analysis, ODE and ODPs, or geometry. However, there is no doubt that there is a fundamental connection between abstract algebra and some parts of Analysis. Indeed, the largest proof in Mathematics is the one of the Theorem of Classification of Finite Simple Groups, here is a link: [Classification of finite simple groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups); which was completed in 2004 and supposed between 10000 and 20000 pages of mathematical skills projected in a bunch of documents.

Which applications have abstract algebra in general (not only group theory, but also ring theory, fields, modules, etc) in the professional world (without including teaching or research)? Is it possible to apply pure abstract algebra in a job, or is this just a drem?

Comment: What is "the professional world"? I am a professor, which by definition is a professional: I am paid for my work. So you probably mean something a little narrower than "you are paid to do it."

Comment: Exactly, I should have specified any job which is not directly related to teaching. This is, private corporations for example

Comment: So then say that, not "in the professional world". And are you also excluding research? Not every job involving research involves teaching. And just so you know: the largest employer of mathematicians in the United States is the National Security Agency, where abstract algebra is certainly used.

Comment: Crystallographers use groups to identify molecules by examining the symmetries observed when scatting light off them. Invertible affine transformations form a group and many geometric programming tasks involve affine transformations.

Comment: I expect the poster is looking for "real world applications" :)

Comment: Exactly, that is what I was looking for

Comment: Again: if that is what you want, then you should say so **in the post**, not in the comments. Use that "Edit" button. And did you search the site? Googling "applications of Group Theory" yielded quite a bit, including [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/324253/742).

Comment: Crystallography. Cryptography. Quantum computing. Quantum mechanics. [Knowing you can't have a mindless method for flipping your mattress that doesn't remember what you did the last time](https://www.americanscientist.org/article/group-theory-in-the-bedroom#:~:text=All%20possible%20turns%20and%20flips,and%20yaw%20(Y)%20axes.)....

Comment: See the answers and comments to [Applications of abstract algebra outside of mathematics and suitable textbook](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/18977/745) *AND* [Are there real world applications of finite group theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/324253/13130) *AND* [Do groups, rings and fields have practical applications in CS? If so, what are some?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/449066/13130) and [these others](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/324253).